# Does the activity on the meta site influence how the main site is valued?

Tags: support, meta

The [statistics on the Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95499/esperanto-language) only show the activity on the main site. Does the activity on the meta site (this very site) influence how the site is perceived?

I imagine that a meta site where nobody would ask about the acceptable questions, the acceptable tags, which questions to ask, or which tags to use would have a negative effect on how the main site is seen, but in which degree does the activity on the meta site influence the main site *destiny*?